# Eric5: Update module imports

Tags: python, import

I'm using eric5 for my python projects and I really like it.
However I don't understand how to force Eric5 to re-import modules before running a script.

Example of my workflow.
My modules

== mainfile.py ==

```
import mymodule
# some more code
```

=================

1.) First run of `mainfile.py` with "Start->Run Script".

2.) Then I modify `mymodule.py` and re-run with "Start->Run Script"

3.) I find out that the modification in `mymodule.py` has not included in the `mainfile.py`. There was no re-import of the updated file done.

4.) Currently I'm helping myself by closing and opening the entire Eric5 project. This works but is not very elegant. I assume that there is a more convenient way?

Comment: `reload` in py2, `imp.reload` in py3.3, `importlib.reload` in py3.4 ...